# How to detect a length of array in a request variable?

Tags: javascript, jsp

Request variable `${taskInArray}` is an array with values. 
How can I detect a length of that array with javascript? 
A compilator shows me an errors.

```
<script>

    var length;

    $(document).ready(function() {

        length = ${taskInArray}.length; //Syntax error on token "}", delete this token

    }); //Syntax error on token "}", delete this token

</script>
```

Comment: what is ${taskInArray} , is it JSP value or JS value

Comment: `Request variable ${taskInArray} is an array` - not in javascript it isn't

Comment: @JaromandaX it's a JSP request value

Comment: @rozerro what does the javascript look like in the browser

Comment: @JaromandaX `length = [Ljava.lang.String;@20a11899.length;` and this line shows an error

Comment: so, clearly `[Ljava.lang.String;@20a11899` is not an array, it's not even valid javascript - hence my statement that it isn't an array is quite correct

Comment: @JaromandaX  `${taskInArray}` is actually an array of strings

Comment: one more solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/26962901/5829191

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing two different codes. The key is to realize, **where** and **when** each code is executed - JSP on the server when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is sent to the browser) and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response.

So, on the server side, you need to convert your `taskInArray` into a JSON string, and pass this string to your (browser-side) JavaScript code. E.g. using the [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
// ...
String jsonTaskInArray = new Gson().toJson(taskInArray);
request.setAttribute('jsonTaskInArray', jsonTaskInArray);
```

And then, in JavaScript

```
var tasks = ${jsonTaskInArray} ; 
length = tasks.length;
```