# Getting error in jsp while traversing list of string

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I am sending a list of string from my controller to my jsp

```
model.addAttribute("itemList", Arrays.asList("first", "second"));
```

And trying to get them in my jsp

```
<c:forEach var="singleItem" items="${itemList}">
                console.log(${singleItem});
</c:forEach>
```

But i am getting the following error

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: first is not defined 
ReferenceError: first is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console.log` takes a string. The JS is rendered on the server, and run on the client. `${singleItem}` needs to be:

- In quotes
- JS-escaped

Look at your rendered page: you will see

```js
console.log(first); 
console.log(second);
```

JS thinks those are variable references (because in JS, they are).

*Just* wrapping it in quotes is insufficient, because the string being rendered may have its *own* quotes, e.g.,

```java
Arrays.asList("first's doodad")
```

Without JS escaping, and using JS single-quotes:

```js
console.log('${singleItem}');
```

would render as:

```js
console.log('first's doodad');
```

which is invalid JS.

Understanding where code is run, and knowing to check the rendered HTML, are important. When rendering into an environment it's important to understand the environment you're rendering in to, same as when rendering HTML into HTML.

Comment: Can you please help me how can i count the number of items in the list? i want to print the number of elements outside the loop

Comment: @simsima https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962901/438992